# How to understand the use of the ... Select 1 from ... an expression in SQL

Tags: postgresql

**Task:**

Find the employee with the highest salary among each department

**Data:**

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE employee_id_seq; 

create table Employee
(
    id_emp    int DEFAULT nextval('employee_id_seq')
                           NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
    name_emp  varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    mgr_id_fk int          not null,

    job_emp   text         NOT NULL, 
    salary    int          NOT NULL,
    date_emp  date         NOT NULL,
    dep_ID_fk int          NOT NULL
);

ALTER SEQUENCE employee_id_seq
    OWNED BY employee.id_emp; 

create table Manager
(
    id_mgr   int not null primary key unique,
    type_mgr varchar(255)
);

ALTER table Employee
    add FOREIGN KEY (mgr_id_fk) REFERENCES Manager (id_mgr)
        on update cascade 
        on delete set null;

create table Department
(
    id_depart   int          NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY unique,
    name_depart varchar(255) not null,
    address     text,
    phone       text
);

insert into Manager (id_mgr, type_mgr)
VALUES
       (1006, 'juniormgr'),
       (1004, 'middlemgr'),
       (1005, 'seniormgr');

insert into Department (id_depart, name_depart, address, phone)
values (1, 'Sales', 'Sydney', '0425 198 053'),
       (2, 'Accounts', 'Melbourne', '0429 198 955'),
       (3, 'Admin', 'Melbourne', '0428 198 758'),
       (4, 'Marketing', 'Sydney', '0427 198 757');


insert into Employee(id_emp, name_emp, mgr_id_fk, job_emp, salary, date_emp, dep_ID_fk)
values (nextval('employee_id_seq'), 'ken Adams', 1006, 'Salesman', 70000, '2008-04-12', 1),
       (nextval('employee_id_seq'), 'Ru Jones', 1004, 'Salesman', 65000, '2010-01-18', 1),
       (nextval('employee_id_seq'), 'Dhal Sim', 1006, 'Accountant', 88000, '2001-03-07', 2),
       (nextval('employee_id_seq'), 'Ellen Honda', 1006, 'Manager', 118000, '2001-03-17', 1),
       (nextval('employee_id_seq'), 'Mike Bal', 1005, 'Receptionist', 68000, '2006-06-21', 3),
       (nextval('employee_id_seq'), 'Martin Bison', 1005, 'CEO', 210000, '2010-07-12', 3),
       (nextval('employee_id_seq'), 'Shen Li', 1004, 'Salesman', 86000, '2014-09-18', 1),
       (nextval('employee_id_seq'), 'Zang Ross', 1004, 'Salesman', 65000, '2017-02-02', 1),
       (nextval('employee_id_seq'), 'Sagar Kahn', 1005, 'Salesman', 70000, '2016-03-01', 1);
```

Such a request will give you the necessary information :

```sql
select * from employee e
where not exists (select 1 from employee e2
                  where e2.dep_id_fk = e.dep_id_fk
                    and e2.salary > e.salary);
```

My reasoning:

1. First, a subquery will be executed and Postgres will save this temporary result
2. then the rest of the request will be executed

```sql
select * from employee e
where not exists ...
```

where **not exists** , excludes all matches found in the subquery

Question:

This code causes a misunderstanding of how it still works,
because everything here is illogical in my opinion.

For example, how does this work

```sql
select 1 from employee e2
                  where e2.dep_id_fk = e.dep_id_fk
                    and e2.salary > e.salary
```

**select 1 from**  - what does this expression even do ?

**e2.dep_id_fk = e.dep_id_fk** - this is a check of the same table ( in the subquery and in the main query), but why ?

**e2.salary > e.salary** - and that's why ?

Comment: The EXISTS operator only checks if at least one row is returned. It does not care at all about the actual columns in the sub-query (they are never evaluated anyways)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you need to understand:

1. What is a co-related subquery
2. How does the (NOT) EXISTS operator work.

A co-related subquery is run once for each row that is returned from the outer query.  You can imagine this as a kind of nested loop, where for each row returned by the outer query, the sub-query is executed by using the values of the columns from the outer query.

So if the outer query processes the row for `'ken Adams'` it will take the value `1` from `dep_id_fk` and the value `70000` of the column salary and essentially run:

```
select 1 
from employee e2
where e2.dep_id_fk = 1 --<< this value is from the outer query
  and e2.salary > 70000 --<< this value if from the outer query
```

If that query returns no rows, the row from the outer query is included in the result. Then the database proceeds with the next row in the outer query and does the same again until all rows from the outer query are processed and either included in or excluded from the result.

However the NOT EXISTS and EXISTS operators check **only** check for the presence of *rows* from the sub-query. The actual value(s) returned from the sub-query are completely irrelevant.

A lot of people incorrectly assume that `select 1` is somehow cheaper than `select *` in the sub-query - but this is a totally wrong assumption. The expression is never even evaluated, so it's completely irrelevant what is selected there. If you think `select *` is more logical than `select 1` than use that.

To prove that the expression is never evaluated (or even looked at), you can use one that would otherwise throw an exception.

```
select * 
from employee e
where not exists (select 1/0
                  from employee e2
                  where e2.dep_id_fk = e.dep_id_fk
                    and e2.salary > e.salary);
```

If you run `select 1/0` outside of a sub-query used for an EXISTS or NOT EXISTS condition, it would result in an error. But the EXISTS operator never even looks at the expressions in the SELECT list.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try

```sql
select *
from employee e
where not exists(select 'foo'
                 from employee e2
                 where e2.dep_id_fk = e.dep_id_fk
                   and e2.salary > e.salary);
```

or

```sql
select *
from employee e
where not exists(select 42
                 from employee e2
                 where e2.dep_id_fk = e.dep_id_fk
                   and e2.salary > e.salary);
```

2 queries return same result:

[image]

Therefore, the purpose of `1` is just supports check *existing*.

Comment: In Postgres you can even remove the expression completely e.g. `select from employee e2 ...` or use an expression that would otherwise throw an error `select 1/0 from ...`